# Is there some problem with the following c code

Tags: c, scanf

When i compile and run this program my input string is not same as output.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n; char ch[100];
    scanf("%d : %5s", &n, ch);
    printf("%d : %s", n, ch); // there is some problem with output of the string
    return 0;
}
```

input:

```
45
asdf
```

output:

```
45 : ∟sëuⁿ■a
```

Comment: please include input, output and expected output in the question

Comment: what is "some problem"

Comment: You should never ever use `scanf` without checking the return value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scanf part will read until it hits the colon, but it will not read the colon itself, which means the following integer will not be read correctly and the rest of the string will be parsed incorrectly (if at all).

Try removing the colon (:) from the scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n; char ch[100];
    scanf("%d %5s", &n, ch);
    printf("%d : %s", n, ch);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: After the colon there is no "following integer".

Comment: %5s means that only five characters words will be stored in variable text

Comment: Also, you can remove the whitespace character between `%d` and `%s`.

Comment: @Vinoth.R correct, but that is format string, not input. The whole `%5s` will not be reached at all.

Answer (score 0):

get rid of the ":" in scanf(), nothing is read after the "%d" input

Comment: Thanks. So anything in the scanf other than format specifiers cause errors?

Comment: @776Shivamrut No, but you must enter it exactly as it is in the format string